# Cannot Connect To MSSQL Server

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, database, php7

I am using `php 7` and trying to connect to mssql server.  I have this code:

```
<?php
$serverName = "server"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"database", "UID"=>"userid", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

but when I open the page, I get this error

> Call to undefined function SQLSRV_CONNECT()

Is it an issue with the php version or simply an additional package that I should add to my Joomla install?

Comment: Welcome to JSE.  Please take our [tour] and consider telling us a little about yourself and your Joomla journey by editing your profile.

Comment: Relevant reading: [Configuring sqlserver](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Configuring_sqlserver) and [Connect To SQL Server On Joomla](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42775833/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sharky said, it seems like your `SQLSRV` extension isn't enabled. You can manually activate it by changing your `php.ini` file, enabling this extension and downloading the drivers.

PHP Documentation says:

> The SQLSRV extension is enabled by adding appropriate DLL file to your
> PHP extension directory and the corresponding entry to the php.ini
> file. The SQLSRV download comes 8 driver files, four of which are for
> PDO support.

You can download the file here

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/download-drivers-php-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

Once you have downloaded the file, you have to execute it.
A box will prompt asking where you want to extract.

You can extract to wherever you want to and then copy to your php extension folder or you can directly extract to your PHP extension folder.  Usually your extension folder lies in: `your-php-folder\bin\php\your-php-version` or `your-php-folder\bin\php` and it's called `ext`. So the final path is something like this: `your-php-folder\bin\php\ext`.

To enable the dll in your `php.ini` file, you have to open it, and search for `Extensions` then add the dll like this:

```
extension=name-of-your-dll-you-downloaded-and-extracted-to-the-ext-folder.dll
```

Example:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_81_s.dll
```

If that doesn't work, you can try simply `extension=sqlsrv_81_s` leaving out php_ and .dll

Comment: I add the downloaded files to my extensions directory.  What do I modify my php.ini file to?  I'm not clear on what I need to add to that

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not related to Joomla. You are manually calling a function which does not exist on your PHP installation. This most likely means the required SQLSRV PHP extension is not enabled.

Comment: once I SSH into the box, what command do i run to enable this function?

Answer (score 0):

If you Joomla work and need to access the database use Joomla functional to connect database

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
```

Comment: Hello Dmitry, in this case he's trying to connect to the database using MSSQL. So he has to set up an environment first before start using MSSQL Server. But it seems like he managed to solve his problem.